# Problems when displaying text on hover on SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to display a text by scaling it whenever the user hover on a SVG element(image).
However i got two problems :

- The text is not scaling
- The text start flickering.

I would appreciate any help.

```css
.hex {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    z-index: -100;   
}
.description text{
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

.hex:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  
}

.hex:hover + .description text {
  display: block;
  
}
```

```html
<svg>
        <g class="hex">
            <use xlink:href="#pod" transform="translate(50,50)" fill="#00d0e8" />
            <a xlink:href="#" target="_top">
                <image xlink:href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/100" transform="translate(50,50)" width="100" height="100"/>
            </a>
        </g>
        <g class="description">
            <text transform="translate(70,100)" font-family="Verdana" font-size="28" fill="blue">Hello</text>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your SVG work a lot easier by

- adding a `viewBox`
- removing all those `translate`
- use absolute positioning where it is easier to read (image)
- use % percentage positioning where easier to read/use (text)
- use text attributes to center (middle) the text
- if you want the hover on the `svg`, change the selector to:
  `svg.zoom:hover g { transform: scale(1.5) }`

```html
<style>
  .zoom g {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }
  .zoom g:hover        { transform: scale(1.5) }
  .zoom text           { opacity: 0 }
  .zoom g:hover > text { opacity: 1 }

  svg { /* only to make it look nice and show size in this SO snippet */
    background: pink;
    height: 180px;
  }
</style>

<svg class="zoom" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
 <g>
  <image x="25" y="25" width="100" height="100" href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/100" />
  <text  x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" 
         font-family="Verdana" font-size="36" fill="blue">Hello</text>
 </g>
</svg>
<svg class="zoom" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
 <g>
  <image x="25" y="25" width="100" height="100" href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/200" />
  <text  x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" 
         font-family="Verdana" font-size="36" fill="blue">World</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What if i wanna one single svg element with g elements in it, instead of 2 svg elements ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution:

1. Put `<text>` under `<g class="hex">`
2. Use `opacity` for the hovered `<text>` (`visibility` also works)
3. Remove `display` and `z-index` attributes, they're meaningless in SVG

```css
.hex {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.hex > text {
  opacity: 0;
}


.hex:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.hex:hover > text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g class="hex">
    <use xlink:href="#pod" transform="translate(50,50)" fill="#00d0e8" />
    <a xlink:href="#" target="_top">
      <image xlink:href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/100" transform="translate(50,50)" width="100" height="100"/>
    </a>
    <text transform="translate(70,100)" font-family="Verdana" font-size="28" fill="blue">Hello</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hex {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.hex text {
    display: none;
}

.hex:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.hex:hover text {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g class="hex">
        <use xlink:href="#pod" transform="translate(50,50)" fill="#00d0e8" />
        <a xlink:href="#" target="_top">
            <image xlink:href="https://placeholder.pics/svg/100" transform="translate(50,50)" width="100" height="100" />
        </a>
                <text transform="translate(70,100)" font-family="Verdana" font-size="28" fill="blue">Hello</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```